# access one property value from another javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two json values,

```
var  first = {name:'smith',lastname:'john'}
var second = {age:18,city:'NY'}
```

How can i get  `second.age`  using object of `first` ?

Comment: You can't. The two objects are unrelated, programmatically.

Comment: is that possible using Javascript oops concept?

Comment: Only by adding `second` to `first`. Robin shows you an example of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but you want to access "second" while you acctually only have access to "first".

Without creating some sort of correlation it would be impossible. You could do

```
first.second = second;
```

and access it through first by using first.second, for instance

```
first.second.age
```

Comment: thanks @robin for your response, is there any other way to achieve using JS object inheritance concepts?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're after. The closest to object inheritance, unless you are willing to use ES6 and transpile it, would be protyping, [refer to this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype).